# Angular2: Cloning component / HTML element and it's functionality

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

So, the question is fairly simple...

I have a table and some angular logic on it (calculating styles, etc)... specifically I have this on THs

```
[class.hidden] = "column.group !== 'key-data' && currentTableView !== column.group"
```

For my table sticky headers functionality I need to clone the table and position it fixed.. using a directive, that does something like this (simplified)

```
let newTable = element.cloneNode(true);
body.appendChild(newTable);
```

obviously the angular logic is not applied to the newTable, but I want it to be...

How do I do it?

Comment: Why don't you just create a new instance with the same data? I don't think there is a way to clone it this way.

Comment: New instance + storing/getting properties (via service or in worst case from localStorage,..)

Comment: is not for getting data.... is for switching visible and hidden columns. There is some angular logic for ngClass put on THs... I want to retain the same logic on cloned THs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I did some research and this is what I came up with.

You can do it and it isn't actually that hard using templates and the `[ngTemplateOutlet]`. This is how it works:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ng-template #temp>
        <h1 [ngStyle]="{background: 'green'}">Test</h1>
        <p *ngIf="bla">Im not visible</p>   
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="temp"></ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="temp"></ng-container>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
    bla: boolean = false;
    @ContentChild('temp') testEl: any;
}
```

So you create a reference template, add all of your logic inside of it, and then you just create as many copies of the template using the `[ngTemplateOutlet]`. All of the inner bindings and angular functionality is retained.

Here is a working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jPt5eKUfLUe9FxnLH8bL?p=preview

As you can see I've tested it with `*ngIf` and `[ngStyle]` and they work as expected and I don't see any reason why any other kind of directive wouldn't work.

You can even use `*ngFor` but then you need to provide the `[ngOutletContext]`.
I've done that in a library I'm working on you can see an example here:

https://github.com/flauc/ng2-simple-components/blob/master/src/select/select.component.ts

Comment: Looks good... would like to award you the bounty but haven't checked/tested it yet if that's what I am looking for... it looks like it is close

Comment: I've used it successfully a few times now and i hope it works for you as well.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function, <ng-template should be used instead of <template>

Comment: Thanks @VictorBredihin the implementation changed from when this was written. I've updated my answer so it's aligned with the current version of angular.