# How to dynamically add a cloned node in angular2 (equivalent to cloneNode)

Tags: angular, dom, clonenode, ng-template

In Angular2, I need to duplicate a node rather than moving it in some cases. That node has angular2 properties so cloneNode doesn't work. How can I do it?

*what doesn't work

```
    let el = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById(divId);
    if ((<HTMLElement>el.parentNode).id == 'itsMe')
        el = <HTMLElement>el.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById(anotherId).appendChild(el);
```

*what would work, from [Angular2: Cloning component / HTML element and it's functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081979/angular2-cloning-component-html-element-and-its-functionality/39220492)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <template #temp>
        <h1 [ngStyle]="{background: 'green'}">Test</h1>
        <p *ngIf="bla">Im not visible</p>   
    </template>
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="temp"></template>
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="temp"></template>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
    bla: boolean = false;
    @ContentChild('temp') testEl: any;
}
```

But how to add a template dynamically?

Comment: Have you tried to use `ngFor`?

Comment: What for? I want to do it dynamically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's use the following markup for illustration:

```html
<p>Paragraph One</p>
<p>Paragraph Two</p>   <!-- Let's try to clone this guy -->
<p>Paragraph Three</p>
```

**Option 1 - Manually wrap the element to clone inside a `<template>` tag**

This is basically what you did, only instead of printing out the template with `ngTemplateOutlet`, grab a reference to it in your component's class and insert it imperatively with `createEmbeddedView()`.

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <p>Paragraph One</p>
      <template #clone>
        <p>Paragraph Two</p>
      </template>
      <p>Paragraph Three</p>

      <button (click)="cloneTemplate()">Clone Template</button>

      <div #container></div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent{
    // What to clone
    @ViewChild('clone') template;

    // Where to insert the cloned content
    @ViewChild('container', {read:ViewContainerRef}) container;

    constructor(private resolver:ComponentFactoryResolver){}

    cloneTemplate(){
        this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
    }
}
```

In this example, I'm inserting the "clone" at a specific location in the markup (`<div #container></div>`), but you could also append it at the bottom of the current component's template.

Also note that the original `<p>Paragraph Two</p>` is no longer visible.

**Option 2 - Use a structural directive**

If you want to clone an element **at its current location**, ending up with:

```html
<p>Paragraph One</p>
<p>Paragraph Two</p>   <!-- Original paragraph -->
<p>Paragraph Two</p>   <!-- Cloned paragraph   -->
<p>Paragraph Three</p>
```

Then you could create a structural directive `*clone` and apply it to the paragraph to clone, like this:

```
<p>Paragraph One</p>
<p *clone>Paragraph Two</p>
<p>Paragraph Three</p>
```

Interestingly, what a structural directive does is wrap the element it is applied to inside a `<template>` tag. Pretty similar to what we did in option 1, only in that case we have NO CONTROL over the location where the clones are printed out (they will appear where the original paragraph was).

This would essentially replicate `*ngFor`'s behavior so it's probably not very useful. Also, it seems from your comment to `yurzui` that it's not what you want.

Comment: I'm trying option 1, I'd say you have a mistake in `@ViewChild('template')`, it should be `'clone'` (or at least that works for me). Is there a way I could dynamically define where to inject the cloned template? kind of `document.getElementById.createEmbeddedView`?

Comment: @Gerard. Well, you do need an anchor point to insert the cloned template. AFAIK, in the `@ViewChild(selector)` decorator, the `selector` can be either a directive/component or a template variable like in my example. The documentation is unclear whether you can use other types of selectors. Maybe try a class selector, e.g. `@ViewChild('.active')` or `@ViewChild('[active]')`.

Comment: Ok, and what matters is that now it works and before you this was completely obscure. Thousand thanks! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: (I've made a question based on your solution, about how to pass a variable to the cloned template, still struggling) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057886/angular2-how-to-dynamically-change-a-value-of-a-custom-directive-in-a-cloned-te