# Angular2, how to pass a variable to a template that is cloned

Tags: angular, angular2-template, cloning

In Angular2 I have a template code that I am cloning whenever the user clicks a button, just like answered here
[How to dynamically add a cloned node in angular2 (equivalent to cloneNode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918325/how-to-dynamically-add-a-cloned-node-in-angular2-equivalent-to-clonenode/41921531#41921531)

I am trying to pass a variable to it, but it doesn't work. What's wrong?

```
import {Component, NgModule, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <template #clone let-session>
     <div [id]="session">eps {{session}} ya</div>
    </template>

    <div #container></div>

    <div>
      <button (click)="create()">Hello</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

    @ViewChild('clone') clone:any;
    @ViewChild('container', {read:ViewContainerRef}) container:any;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  create(){
    let session = 'testing';
        this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.clone, {context: {$implicit: session}});
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And the plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/pWeQfTLroOjKoyKnaZvL?p=preview

Comment: Why don't you just pass the `id` to an input of the directive?

Comment: I will read about it, right now I wouldn't know how to do it

Comment: It would be helpful to see more code. What is the directive? Actually you could even pass the element itself, so you don't have to query for it.

Comment: I've added the code for the directive (if it helps).

Comment: Where do you do the cloning? Why don't you just keep a reference? What value do you want to dynamically change?

Comment: I do the cloning in the component that has the template (external template). When the user clicks the button (as many times as he wishes) then I clone the template. So what I don't know is how many clones the user will want, that's why I need it to be dynamic. Right now the cloning works, but the drag-and-drop does not because the directive of the template does not contain the information of the clone when I (dynamically) change it

Comment: So when I clone the template I need to change its ID for a unique one, and then I need to add this ID to the custom directive as well. I suspect that I could put a variable in the custom directive and that I could access it and change it, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've updated your [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y7GHxpm3fVuvC04uemMA?p=preview), basically answer could be found in [#8368](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8368):

```
<template #clone let-context="context">
 <div [id]="context.session">eps {{context.session}} ya</div>
</template>

this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.clone, {context: {session: session}});
```

Comment: Thanks! And could you please expand in why your answer does work and why Günter's one does not? Or more importantly, is there any documentation I've skipped that described this? (I'm afraid your link is obscure to me)

Comment: It looks like documentation for method `createEmbeddedView` is quite limited. Context parameter contains all properties available in template, your example can be simplified to `{session:session}` and `let-session="session"`.

Answer (score 1):

```ts
create_new_session(s : string) {
    this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.clone, {context: {$implicit: session}});
}
```

```ts
<template #clone let-session>
<section [id]="session"
    [bookmark_draggable_target]="{event_type:'moving_sessions',zone:'title_template'}"
    (drop_here)="onDrop($event)">
</section>
</template>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html#!#createEmbeddedView-anchor

Comment: So then I could change to `,zone:newId}` ?

Comment: Might do as well. Hard for me to tell without knowing what the code does with this data.

Comment: I have no problem at all in posting the code, but I feel that this is like flooding the page. I'm adding some more in a minute. For the drag and drop implementation I've followed this article http://www.radzen.com/blog/angular-drag-and-drop/

Comment: The code still doesn't show where  you do `createEmbeddedView`. This is about how to get the id passed along, isn't it?

Comment: Now it is added

Comment: I updated my answer. This way you have a `session` variable available inside the template and you can pass it to directives or use it otherwise. I used it to set the `id` property, but I'd discouraged using an `@Input() id;`. Rather use a different name because this often causes problems because it conflicts with the `id` property of `HTMLElement`.

Comment: I can't it make to work. I get the <section id=undefined>.

Comment: I've made a plunker here, it also shows undefined https://plnkr.co/edit/pWeQfTLroOjKoyKnaZvL?p=preview

Comment: I'm on vacarion, can have a look when I'm back