# Placeholder will not disappear when typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material, angular6

When clicking on a button, an element with the class of `emails` should be cloned.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="add-user">
  <div class="email-container">
    <div class="emails">
        <mat-form-field class="email full-width">
            <input matInput class="email-field" type="email" required placeholder="E-Mail">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
    <i class="material-icons icon" id="addEmailField" (click)="clone()">add_box</i>
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
public clone(): void {
   const clone = document.querySelector('.emails').cloneNode(true); // clone the selector .emails
   document.querySelector('.email-container').appendChild(clone); // append it to .email-container
}
```

The cloning part works but the problem is the placeholder of the cloned element. If I type something into the text field, it won't disappear.

This is how it looks if I type into a cloned element:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? **Run and test it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-clone-pbimzc?file=app%2Fissue-list%2Fissue-list.component.ts).**

Comment: It looks like after the first one, you're cloning multiple textboxes for each input that are overlaying eachother. This is probably because of `document.querySelector('.emails').cloneNode(true); ` - this will grab all `.emails`, even if you have 2, 3 or 4 - and clone them all.

Comment: Suggest you use array and `ngFor` instead of manipulating the dom yourself

Comment: I don't know material, but it looks like it's not an ordinary placeholder. It's a label that moves up on focus, so I guess its functionality is initiated on page load, so you need to look for a way to re-initiate the material functionality on the new fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cloneNode()` clones DOM - it does not clone Angular objects. You must clone Angular components the "Angular" way. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41921531/9226213.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me. I have posted an answer that describes how I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a template with `ng-template` solves this problem. Show the template whenever the button is clicked and also show it when the page gets loaded with `ngOnInit()`.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="add-user">
    <ng-template #email>
        <mat-form-field class="email full-width">
            <input matInput class="email-field" type="email" required placeholder="E-Mail">
        </mat-form-field>
    </ng-template>
    <div #furtherEmails></div>
</form>
<i class="material-icons icon" id="addEmailField" (click)="clone()">add_box</i>
```

**TS:**

```
@ViewChild('email') email;
@ViewChild('furtherEmails', {read: ViewContainerRef}) furtherEmails;

public clone(): void {
    this.furtherEmails.createEmbeddedView(this.email);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.clone();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the material theming in your styles.css?

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the input to a variable in the ts file and then create a mat placeholder instead and bind the ngModelChange property of the input field to a function that will disable or enable the mat placeholder. Depending on if the input field is empty.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="email full-width">
        <mat-placeholder *ngIf="showPlaceholder">E-mail</mat-placeholder>
        <input matInput class="email-field" type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" (ngModelChange)="togglePlacholder()" required />
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
email: string = ''
showPlaceholder: boolean = true

togglePlaceholder() {
    if(this.email !== '') { 
        this.showPlaceholder = false
    }else {
        this.showPlaceholder = true
    }
}
```